# Delphi Chromium CEF3 won't resize

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am creating a browser in delphi 7 using TChromium. All works fine except that Chromium Browser maintains the same size it had when it was first created. Short: Chromium browser won't resize on maximize/minimize. TChromium component is created dinamically: 
TChrom[MainPages.PageCount]:=TChromium.Create(self);
TChrom[MainPages.PageCount].CreateBrowser(TabSheet,'');

[image: chromium won't resize]

Comment: You must setup its `Anchors`, or use a certain `Align` (in your case probably `alClient`). But that applies to all visual controls, not only Chromium.

Comment: Can we see your code that handles the resizing?

Comment: All componenets (a single PageControl) is aligned alclient. The rest of components are created at runtime. The Tabsheet is also aligned alclient by default. I don't know how to handle resize of TChromium, i tryed to use a TChromiumWindow aligned alClient and it happens the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed a TCEFWindowParent with Tabsheet as parent and aligned al client and then CreateBrowser in TCEFWindowParent.

Comment: Can u share code please? I have a some trouble, can't find easy example for it =\